# Guzzle 6 PUT request not sending form params

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I have the following code that I use whenever I want to make POST requests using Guzzle:

```
$request = $client->request('POST', $url, [
'form_params' => $params,
  'headers' => [
    'Referer' => '(intentionally removed)',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ]
]);
```

The code works without any issues and the information within $params is always sent, however when I change the request type from POST to PUT so that the request becomes:

```
$request = $client->request('PUT', $url, [
'form_params' => $params,
  'headers' => [
    'Referer' => '(intentionally removed)',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ]
]);
```

The request suddenly stops sending the data contained within $params.

I have tested the endpoint the request is send to with Insomnia with both POST and PUT requests and both types are processed as expected, so I am certain the issue is not there.

What can be causing the data from Guzzle to be send using the POST method but not when using the PUT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour described in guzzle documentation [form-params](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params)

> form_params - Used to send an application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request.

Probably, you enough pass the parameters in [json](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#json) format:

```
$request = $client->request('PUT', $url, [
  'json' => $params,
  'headers' => [
    'Referer' => '(intentionally removed)',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
  ]
]);
```